# Decontaminating the training data set - any idea why it works?

Tags: classification, binary-data

**TL;DR**

I have to decontaminate a training data set that includes irrelevant observations that will harm the quality of any statistical estimation and inference. It is of course initially unknown which observations must be discarded, and no out-of-sample information to help. I can obtain, using the sample itself, an imperfect criterion for this purpose, and then apply it iteratively -and simulations show that the procedure is successful. But I would like to obtain some theoretical justification as to why this works.

Are there any theoretical results on the task of decontaminating a training data set using the training data set itself?

**TS;DR**

I am trying to match my situation to any available theoretical results related, I guess, to binary classification and data sample decontamination.

The situation: I have a size-$n$ sample $\{\mathbf y,\mathbf X\}$, where $y$ takes only the values $0/1$, $\mathbf X$ is a matrix of any kind of random variables. The sample is comprised of two sub-samples. Neither the population proportions nor the sample proportions of the two sub-samples are known.

For the one sub-sample, say $A$, the relation $\mathbf y_A = g(\mathbf X_A;
\beta) + \mathbf e $ holds, where $\beta$ is an unknown parameter vector and $\mathbf e$ is a conditional expectation function error. For the other sub-sample, say $B$, $y_{Bi}$ is a *constant*, either of value $0$, or of value $1$, so I cannot use $y$ to separate the sub-samples (essentially I have *three* sub-samples, but I can initially lump the two of them together for my purposes).

The two sub-samples come initially from the same population. What links the two is that, at an underlying level, if $g(X_i;\beta) \in S$ (for some known compact real-line interval $S$), then the $i$-th observation belongs to sub-sample $A$. If $g(X_j;\beta) \notin S$, then the $j$-th observation belongs to sub-sample $B$.

My purpose is to estimate $\beta$, so the observations belonging to sub-sample $B$ are "irrelevant" for this purpose, and "contaminate" the sample. I am also interested in obtaining an accurate classifier to be able to characterize the quantitative features of the sub-samples/sub-populations.

I can use the whole sample to obtain estimates $\hat \beta$, but of course, since the estimator will use also the "irrelevant" observations, it will be a biased and inconsistent estimator.

Also, the consequent series of estimates $g_i(X_i;\hat \beta), i=1,...n$ appear to be of unknown classification accuracy: obtaining $g_i(X_i;\hat \beta) \in S$ does not necessarily mean that $g_i(X_i;\beta) \in S$; neither $g_i(X_i;\hat \beta) \notin S$ guarantees that $g_i(X_i;\beta) \notin S$.

***But*** : all simulations I have run show that an iterative "clean-up" operation is successful: if I use the estimated $\hat g_i$ series as a binary classifier in order to discard observations (those for which I get $\hat g_i \notin S$), and then apply the same estimation procedure to the reduced-size sample, obtain new $\hat g_i$, discard observations, re-estimate, etc, I end up with a "clean sample", namely a sample that contains only observations that belong to sub-sample $A$. I may have lost some relevant observations in the process due to wrong classification, but that's a small price to pay, since in this way I do get consistent estimates for $\beta$.

To be accurate, I end up with an "almost" clean sample, and "almost" consistent estimates for $\beta$, but this has to do with the finite sample. When I run the simulations with very large sample sizes, I end up with essentially perfect estimates for $\beta$, even though in the process I may have discarded half of the observations.

What is my problem? I want to *prove* that this iterative procedure, even if it uses initially a biased/inconsistent etc binary classifier, *improves on itself*, by making the sample less and less contaminated, the classifier more and more accurate, and so the $\hat \beta$ estimator "more and more" consistent and acceptable. Or at least, obtain the conditions/assumptions under which this happens.

I note that the usual set-up where we start with a training data set and then apply the classifier on *new* observations, is not the case here. Here, we start with all available observations, obtain a classifier, and then we apply the classifier to discard observations from the initial sample. I guess what I am doing here can be described as "decontaminating the training data set".

Are there any theoretical results on such a task?

Comment: You might want to read about robust logistic regression. See [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/files/153/6304770.pdf) for a quick intro (Croux, C., and Haesbroeck, G. (2003), "Implementing the Bianco and Yohai estimator for logistic regression", Computational Statistics and Data Analysis, 44, 273-295.)

Comment: sure, don't hesitate if you want further pointers to the literature.

Comment: Tl;dr... but you may want to look up Cook's distance: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/200255